# What does "SP" do?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-switch-online

I recently decided to subscribe to Nintendo Switch Online, so I can play the NES games included in the service.

When I launched the NES Nintendo Switch Online app, I noticed that some games were listed twice, such as Metroid, The Legend of Zelda, Ninja Gaiden, and more. The duplicate appears to have a "SP Special" logo on top of the game's cover art.

[image: Screenshot of NES Nintendo Switch Online]
<sup>Pictured: Ninja Gaiden and Ninja Gaiden SP.</sup>

But what exactly does the "SP" do? What's the difference between SP and non-SP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are "special", modified versions of the games.

How they differ from the original, unmodified version depends on the game.

To find out what's changed, select the game with <kbd>X</kbd> (Details) to see an information window.

[image: Screenshot of Metroid SP information window]

In Metroid SP, for instance, you start at the battle against Ridley with all of your equipment, including the Ice Beam weapon.